# How to get the value of ListView and save it in the EditText or something else in another activitiy

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-studio, parcelable

There is any activity with an input field, it calls the second activity with ListView. **I need to get the value from the ListView and return it to the input field in the first activity**. Can not return a value, but the activity switches without errors.

**MainActivity**

```
edTAirportchoice1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edText);
    edText.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data == null) {
        return;

    } String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    edText.setText(name);
    }

}
```

**ListActivity**

```
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s1));
    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s1[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            intent.putExtra("name", s1[position]);
            setResult(1,intent);        
            finish();

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", edText.getText().toString()); //("name", list1.getOnItemClickListener().toString())- the same result
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: In OnItemClick don't start again the activity, use setResult instead. Also the selectedREsult is a Serializable, and you are expecting a string...

Comment: your value is not set in textview ? right ? @l2win36

Comment: yes, value is set in edittext and this value is not returned so @AmitVaghela

Comment: "In OnItemClick don't start again the activity" - right, but Without these lines of code in OnItemClick my listview is not clickable... @Chol

Comment: Yes but do not put this line: startActivity(intent), use setResult(1, intent)

Comment: For some reason it does not work properly, value of listview is not returned, and it looks like " a backbutton to first activity" @Chol

Comment: Put a log in the OnActivityResult to see if it is reached, then take a closer look to the extra, you are putting a serializable, but you are trying to retrieve a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Intent for this purpose,

From `ListActivity` to `MainActivity`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", list1.getOnItemClickListener().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now in `MainActivity` to get this value of name ,

```
String name= getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

Now to set value in your textview of `MainActivity` ,

```
txtView.setText(name);
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the way!

Comment: Can I try it to edittext and return the value there? @AmitVaghela

Comment: Unfortunately not,this value is not returned so. Should I write " String name= getIntent().getStringExtra("name") " in MainActivity in method "onActivityResult" ? @AmitVaghela

Comment: @AmitVaghela Maybe the problem is the announcement of the list in MainActivity, actually that's it  -  private ListView list1 = null;  private String s1[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but still its not working @AmitVaghela

Comment: I updated the post, still result in the list is not saved in editext. There is no error in the debugger. Can you take a look? @AmitVaghela

Comment: what you are getting in 'name' ,  String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name"); @I2win36

Comment: @AmitVaghela I'm sorry I know why it get an error,now everything looks great, Thanks you

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
        intent.putExtra("name", selectedResult); 
        setResult(1, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way of sharing some data between 2 activities is:

```
public static final int REQUEST_LIST = 1;

// Call this to show ListActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_LIST);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LIST:
               if (data == null) return;
               String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
               edText.setText(name);
               break;

            default:
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in ListActivity you need:

```
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s1));
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("name", s1[position]);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);        
        finish();
});
```

Comment: Cool! Good luck in your Android Development carier.